# Assign Div id to variable jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to assign div id to a variable in jQuery .

```
 var tbdiv = null;
    tbdiv= $('#mydiv');
```

But this is throwing error in my jQuery file as  ' Invalid argument '.

I am trying to do the following code which is in javascript

```
var tbdiv =document.getElementById('mydiv');
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the html of the object?

Comment: @williamcarswell i am trying to get element itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `attr`:

```
var tbdiv= $('#mydiv').attr('id');
// or: var tbdiv = $('#mydiv')[0].id;
```

I would though simply do:

```
var tbdiv= '#mydiv'
```

to assign id.

---

If you *MEANT* assigning element itself, this should work fine:

```
var tbdiv = $('#mydiv');
```

Or with vanilla JS:

```
var tbdiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
```

Comment: yes i meant assigning the element itself but var tbdiv = $('#mydiv');
 is throwing an error in my jQuery library

Comment: @user1210982: Make sure that you have included jQuery and specified correct path. Are you using any other JS library also ?

Comment: no i am using jQuery library itself and it is included and all other jQuery codes are working inside same file except this one

Comment: @user1210982: Then make sure you have not assigned same id value to any other element. If issue still persists, then there is something else wrong. The examples I have shown should work fine

Comment: I am still not sure whats wrong with that code my i managed to made it work by var tbdiv = '#mydiv' and then using it $(tbdiv) as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the `div` then the following should work:

```
var tbdiv = $('#mydiv');
```

If you wan't to select the ID of the `div`, then why use jQuery, you already know the ID because you are using it to make the call to jQuery.

Is jQuery loaded? Are you getting any other errors in the console?

Comment: I am still not sure whats wrong with that code my i managed to made it work by var tbdiv = '#mydiv' and then using it $(tbdiv)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason that the code

```
var tbdiv = null;
tbdiv= $('#mydiv');
```

...would throw any kind of exception provided that

1. jQuery is loaded, and
2. jQuery has the `$` symbol. Some other libraries use it, and so jQuery offers [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) mode. If you've included code somewhere calling `noConflict`, `$` will no longer refer to `jQuery` and you'd have to use this instead:

   ```
   tbdiv = jQuery('#mydiv');
   ```

---

Note that your JavaScript example is wrong. It would be `getElementById('mydiv')` (without the `#`, since the argument to `getElementById` is an ID, not a selector).

Comment: i tried jQuery('#mydiv') still its the same seems like something else is wrong

Comment: I am still not sure whats wrong with that code my i managed to made it work by var tbdiv = '#mydiv' and then using it $(tbdiv)

Comment: @user1210982: That makes no sense.